# Count computers(tag) given that their status(tag) = 'OFF' in InfluxDB

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I have a schema like this.

[image]

How do I count the number of currently ON or OFF computers accurately here?

When I query for OFF computers, the expected result should be 0. But I get a 1. Because it takes in to account the 2nd line in the table for DELL1.

My query is

```
SELECT count("count") FROM (SELECT count("value") FROM "meas" WHERE ("status" = 'OFF') AND $timeFilter GROUP BY "computer")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider only the latest `status` of the computer while counting the number of OFF/ON computers.

You can use InfluDB's [LAST](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/query_language/functions/#last) function to get the last report state of each computer. The result of this query can be nested in a subquery and filtered based on the desired state.

```
 SELECT count('last_status') FROM (
                     SELECT last("status") FROM "meas" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY "computer"
   
   ) WHERE last_status = 'OFF' GROUP BY "computer"
```

Comment: "status" is an InfluxDB tag. "value" is the only field which equals one for each series.